# GXT grid data not displaying

Tags: gwt, gxt

I have upgraded from gxt 3.0.1 to 3.1.1 and gwt 2.4 to 2.6.1.

Data is seems to be lading with page nos. and displaying count, but grid data is not displaying.

any solutions for this ?

Comment: Check if the id of item's list is unique.

Comment: Do you see the Grid header?

Comment: Its pagination Grid, shows Grid Header, Page count and Displaying count

Comment: Turmoil to find the cause.. Pls help

Comment: a snapshot will help

Comment: RPC is successful, but not getting data in display.

Comment: have you tried to call forceLayout()?

Comment: yes, didnt help. From sencha support its probelmwith 3.1.1.. So upgrading to higher version. thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From sencha support its problem with 3.1.1.. So upgrading to higher version.

Thanks all